Are translations of trademarks also protected?
For example, say that an American carmaker comes out with a budget car, which they name the "People's Car". Would Volkswagen (German for "People's Car") have grounds to sue?

Wouldn't that actually be the phrase "Volk Wagen" as two words and not a single one? From what I see that is actually combining the two words to make a new one.

@JoeW I have always seen "Volkswagen" translated as "People's Car", so presumably it would go the other way.

It is the combination of two German words, "The name “Volkswagen” is a combination of two German words: “Volk,” meaning people or folk, and “Wagen,” meaning car or vehicle. Translated literally, Volkswagen means “people’s car.”" https://www.kalispellvolkswagen.com/the-meaning-behind-volkswagen/

Synonyms are not usually protected by trademark, so I don't see why a translation would be.

It's important to distinguish between translations (between different languages) and transliterations (between different writing systems). A Russian word transliterated from Cyrillic to Latin characters, for instance, remains a Russian word, not an English (or French or whatever) word.

The Transliteration of Volkswagen is Volkswagen or フォルクスワーゲン or Фольксваген

Example into English: a transliteration of the Korean brand 삼성 is Samsung. A translation is three stars. In western markets, they transliterated while for Chinese-speaking markets, they translated. (The languages are related and it's close in most Chinese dialects, san sheng in Mandarin)

This should be easy to check. For example, here you can see that Volkswagen registered the word mark "VOLKSWAGEN - PEOPLE'S CAR" in the US in 2009, but then cancelled that registration in 2018: https://tsdr.uspto.gov/#caseNumber=79057372&caseType=DEFAULT&searchType=statusSearch.

The relevant law here is The Trademark Doctrine of Foreign Equivalents. Under that doctrine, a foreign word or phrase and its English equivalent may or may not be ruled to be confusingly similar.
Positive examples:

In re DBMG, LLC, Application No. 90185762, in which the trademark for "Sunset Sushi Bar" was denied due to the existence of competitor "Banshoo Sushi Bar" (banshoo is a Japanese word meaning sunset).
In re California Faucets, Inc., 2018 TTAB LEXIS 463, in which the trademark for "SEAGULL" water purifiers was ruled to be confusingly similar to the existing trademark "GAVIOTA" (gaviota is a Spanish word meaning seagull).

However, the doctrine of foreign equivalents only applies when the "ordinary American purchaser" is likely to translate the foreign mark into English. See, for instance:

In re Seiko Sporting Goods USA Inc. v. Kabushiki Kaisha Hattori Tokeiten, in which a court ruled that although SEIKO is a common term in Japanese, it is sufficiently unique among most Americans to warrant a trademark.
General Cigar Co. v. G.D.M. Inc., 988 F. Supp. 647, 660, in which a court ruled that the COHIBA trademark for General Cigar's products held despite it being the generic Taino Indian word for tobacco, since the typical American consumer was unlikely to translate cohiba into English.

In addition, the translation of non-English words can be ruled to violate other trademark requirements. See, for instance, In re Spirits Int’l N.V., 86 USPQ2d, Appeal No. 08-1369, in which the trademark MOSKOVSKAYA was rejected on the grounds that it translates to "[of/from] Moscow" despite the company having no connection to Moscow.
For the Volkswagen example, a court would likely find that German is a sufficiently widely-known language that a competing trademark for "People's Car" is likely to cause confusion among consumers.

Good answer, although I would be more skeptical that "People's Car" would satisfy the doctrine of equivalents for "Volkswagen", in part, because "wagen" is a false friend and means "car" in this context in German, when an ordinary English speaker would assume that it means "wagon".
